# does the direct sum of constant sequences and null sequences gives convergent sequence Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Question: Let $S$ be the vector space of convergent sequences. Let $W$ be the vector subspace of constant sequences and $N$ be the vector space of null sequences. Then show that $S=W\oplus N$

Attempt:

If $S$ is the vector space of convergent sequences then say the sequence be $(x_n)\in S$ then

i)-$(x_n)=(x)+(x_n-x)$ where $(x)\in W$ and $(x_n-x)\in N$  and

ii)-its easy to show that constant sequence which is convergent to $0$ is the zero sequence which is identity of $S$.

Then by the Proposition 1.9 LINEAR ALGEBRA DONE RIGHT By Sheldon Axler we conclude that $S$ is direct sum of $W$ and $N$

and finally can some one say the name of the book from which this problem might have been picked up.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _"Doesn't they mean $S$ to be the vector space of all convergent sequence instead of Sequences?"_ Yes, I think they do mean the vector space of all **convergent** sequences.

Comment: @Use Yes, either they meant the space of convergent seq's or else that's false.

Comment: @StackTD Alright! Am I correct? My attempt?....And can you answer this "and finally can some one say the name of the book from which this problem might have been picked up"

Comment: Yes, that looks okey. I can imagine this is a very common problem which you'll find in many course notes and text books - I can't give you a concrete reference.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this problem in "**Linear Algebra : A Geometric Approach**" by **S. Kumaresan** (page 42 Exercise 2.3.32). 
The given problem asks us to show the vector space of all real sequences $S$ to be the direct sum of two of its subspaces ($W$ and $N$). However, I think he meant the vector space of all real convergent sequences $C$.

Your proof is right. Take any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ and say its limit is $x$. Then the limit of $(y_n)$ where $y_n=x_n-x$ is $0$. We can write $(x_n)=(x)+(y_n)$ which proves that $C=W+N$. Do you see that this was the *only way* we could write $(x_n)$ as the sum of a constant and a null sequence? This observation leads us to the desired conclusion.